# How to create objects in Java using data from each line from a CSV file

Tags: java, arrays, csv, class, object

I have created a Class that has a constructor that takes a string line and after some processing of the data turns it into an object.

I need to feed data from a CSV one line at a time into the constructor to create an object for every line of the file. However from all my searching I cannot figure out how to create these objects as,from what I have learnt, to create object you have to name these objects. Is there a way to create an array of objects so I don't have to name each object? for example the first line would be like Object[0] and so on?

```java
public class Object{
  String Name, Example, Example2;
  Object(String data){
    //Data manipulation to get into Name Example and Example2 creating an
    //object
  }

  public String getName{
    return Name;
  }
}

public class ObjectFeed{
  //This is where I would open the file and feed it line by line into the  
  //object class
}
```

I should be able to use the getter methods i created for the Object class on any line number and it should get that information. I just do not understand how to feed data into Objects and create multiple objects.

Comment: Don't name your classes `Object`, because `Object` class has special meaning in Java. Also use camel case for variable names, for example: `myName`, `example1`, `exampleTwo`, ...

Comment: Can the data have commas in it?  If so, the CSV values may need to be quoted or escaped and you'll need to consider that in the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is coming from a CSV, each cell should be separated by a comma, so you should be able to take the input string `data` and split it.

This could be done like:

```
String[] csvList = data.split(",");
```

You can then assign each element of `csvList` as one of your object's properties, and loop through all of its elements to produce a list of your objects.

```
List<YourObject> objects = new List<YourObject>();

// increment i by the how many properties YourObject has
for (int i = 0; i < csvList.length; i += 2) {
   YourObject obj = new YourObject();
   obj.FirstProperty = csvList[i];
   obj.SecondProperty = csvList[i+1];
   ...
   objects.add(obj);
}
```

Comment: Is `csvList` an array or list?  I wasnt aware you could access list items using array notation

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
public void createYourObjects() {

  List<String> lines = // however you are reading lines from the CSV file

  List<YourObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();
  for(String line in lines) {
    objects.add(methodB(line);
  }
}

public YourObject createYourObjectFrom(String line) {
  List<String> columns = line.spilt(",");
  return new YourObject(columns.get(0), columns.get(1) ..... columns(n-1));  // where n is the size of the list n-1 is the index of the last item in the list
}
```

Its bit pseudocode-ish but I think it illustrates the basic idea.  By using a separate method to construct your object you separate the concern, isolating the creation of your list of objects from the structure of the CSV file.
It also gives you a place to provide any error or special case handling you may need.

In a real world scenario you may need to handle different types of data, translating from `String` to say `int`, and also when a column is empty.
In the case where a column is empty you will get a smaller list of columns, and you will have to handle this.